# How to remove and add class in Angular renderer2 succinctly

Tags: angular

Is it possible to add and remove a class from your element succinctly, in  two line instead of writing a whole bunch of if else statement

Can you do this? (It is not working for me though.)

```js
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,private elRef: ElementRef) {
   const action = isDisabled ? 'addClass' : 'removedClass';
   this.renderer[action](div, 'disabled');
}
```

instead of

```js
if (isDisabled) {
   this.renderer.addClass(div, 'disabled');
} else {
   this.renderer.removeClass(div, 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: Did you try ngClass on the template?

Comment: no because you're basically saying that action is the property of renderer, when really what you want is a method. I would look into ngClass tho. It's really simple to use and helpful

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta Methods are function properties, no more, no less. Bracket notation is a common (in fact, the only) way to access methods dynamically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible to do

```
const action = isDisabled ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
this.renderer[action](div, 'disabled');
```

Or even

```
this.renderer[isDisabled ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'](div, 'disabled');
```

It is *removeClass*, not *remove**d**Class*. And this is exactly the reason why this shouldn't be done.

Bracket notation disables type checking, so it becomes possible to access non-existing properties without triggering type errors.

Another reason is that the code may be harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ngClass` directive (https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to achieve this exact functionality:

```
<div [ngClass]="disabled ? 'disabled' : ''"></div>
```

If you need to use the `renderer` from inside the component class to achieve this, you could use:

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(div, 'class', this.disabled ? 'disabled' : '');
```

See this working Stackblitz with both approaches demonstrated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ywg27

Comment: I stand corrected, updated my answer to be correct. Your answer is the best answer for this question however. Learned something new from it :) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: if you set the whole class attribute this will override existing classes

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

Creating a custom Directive, in order to toggle the related class, so it can be later succinctly used on the template. On these examples, I will perform such action over a dropdown (specifically over a wrapping div with class 'btn-group', which contains a button and a UL element).

**Note:**

1. I'm using Angular 13 in these examples.
2. I'm also using Bootstrap 3 in these examples (3.4.1 specifically),
   therefore the related class here is "open". For bootstrap 4 or 5 you
   must use "show" instead.
3. Obviously, every directive must be registered in App.module (declarations), before being used.

**Option # 1:** Using HostBinding.

> **File:**
> src/app/directives/dropdown-host-binding/dropdown-host-binding.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdownHostBinding]'
})
export class DropdownHostBindingDirective {
  private wasInsideTheElement = false;
  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen(eventData: Event): void {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.wasInsideTheElement = true;
  }

  @HostListener("document:click") clickOut(): void {
    if (!this.wasInsideTheElement) {
      this.isOpen = false;
    }
    this.wasInsideTheElement = false;
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    <!-- Using a custom Dropdown Directive using HostBinding -->
    <div appDropdownHostBinding class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-renderer-toggle">
        Manage recipe <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Add to Shopping List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Option # 2:** Using ElementRef + Renderer2.

> **File:**
> src/app/directives/dropdown-renderer/dropdown-renderer.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdownRenderer]'
})
export class DropdownRendererDirective {
  private wasInsideTheElement = false;
  isOpen = false;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  @HostListener('click') mouseClick(eventData: Event): void {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.executeAction();
    this.wasInsideTheElement = true;
  }

  @HostListener("document:click") clickOut(): void {
    if (!this.wasInsideTheElement) {
      this.isOpen = false;
      this.executeAction();
    }
    this.wasInsideTheElement = false;
  }

  private executeAction(): void {
    const action = this.isOpen ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    this.renderer[action](this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'open');
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    <!-- Using a custom Dropdown Directive using ElementRef & Renderer2  -->
    <div appDropdownRenderer class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
        Manage recipe <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Add to Shopping List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Option # 3:** Combining HostBinding + ElementRef.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdownHostBindingSimpler]'
})
export class DropdownHostBindingSimplerDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) toggleOpen(event: Event) {
    this.isOpen = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) ? !this.isOpen : false;
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    <!-- Using a custom Dropdown Directive using HostBinding & ElementRef  -->
    <div appDropdownHostBindingSimpler class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
        Manage recipe <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Add to Shopping List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Visual Result** (the same for all of them):

[image]

Angular rocks!

Comment: Nice but you would have given some demo link for reference

Comment: No. I would not. A "demo link" is not necessary, at all. All you need is the little piece of code to make it possible. It's very simple. Thanks for your suggestion anyway. Have a good day.