# Angular 6 How to add and remove class using Angular Renderer2

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-renderer2, angular-renderer

I am trying to use angular Renderer2 to add and remove a class in HTML template. 
Here I am facing the difficulties:

1. to add the class once component will load
2. Only the selected item should have the class

I have created a demo in stackblitz. Please [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer2-core?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to see code.

Thank you.

```
<div class="tabs">
<a href="#" (click)="selectTab($event)">Tab 1 </a>
<a href="#" (click)="selectTab($event)">Tab 2 </a>
<a href="#" (click)="selectTab($event)">Tab 3</a>
</div>


constructor(private render:Renderer2){}
selectTab(event:any) {
this.render.addClass(event.target,"test");
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because questions should contain the code needed for answering the question inside of the question. Not with an external link.

Comment: It seems you've also edited your original code with Hrishikesh Kale's suggestion, meaning the code that lead to your question is no longer available.

Comment: Yes, this edit was just to check Hrishikesh Kale's approach, no intention to change the code. I have edited my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about `[ngClass]="{'test': selectedTab== 1}"`

I have created a ts variable calling selectedTab and declared as number

in HTML I've used `[ngClass]="{'test': selectedTab== 1}"` so when selectedTab = 1 test class will be added .

and on click method I have called selectTab(2) sending clicked tab parameter and handled this function in ts like

```
selectTab(selectedTab) {
if(selectedTab == 1){
  this.selectedTab = 1;
}else if(selectedTab == 2){
  this.selectedTab = 2;
}else{
  this.selectedTab = 3;
}  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hrishikesh Kale. This is the one approach to solve the problem. But I was wondering how to solve using Renderer2.

Comment: yes absolutely this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674025/how-to-remove-and-add-class-in-angular-renderer2-succinctly

Comment: that's great happy coding brother.